# Could not spawn process for application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I searched and found some questions with this problem but there're no correct answers or answers at all. How to solve this problem

403 Forbidden

```
[ 2015-01-15 02:37:25.2282 24300/b638eb40 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application ........../current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
          Error ID: 71201b7d
    ....
          Message from application: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
        #rake 10.1.0 not found in GEM_PATH
        /home/deploy/................n `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/bin/rdoc (Errno::EACCES)

        from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
        bundler 1.7.12
        executable-hooks 1.3.2
        rdoc 4.1.0

        extconf failed, exit code 1`enter code here`
        Gem files will remain installed in .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited this file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default  this way:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        rails_env           production;
        root /home/username/app-name/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name domain-name;
        passenger_enabled   on;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }}
```

And it's working now.

ps. I also pointed passenger to rvm version of ruby in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
passenger_ruby /home/deplopy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby;
```